# Pandas - Select indexes where other column rows meet two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am unsure if question is phrased precisely enough, I hope that code example will explain issue better.

I have dataframe:

```
                                 links                         title
url                                                                         
https://example.com           /feed.xml                       EXAMPLE
https://example.com           /tags.html                      EXAMPLE
https://example.com           /tags.html                      EXAMPLE
https://example.com           /about                          EXAMPLE
https://example.com           /feed.xml                       EXAMPLE
https://example.com           /feed.xml                       EXAMPLE
https://example222.com        /about/                         EXAMPLE222
https://example222.com        /about/                         EXAMPLE222
https://example333.com        /atom.xml                       EXAMPLE333
https://example333.com        /archives                       EXAMPLE333
https://example333.com        /about                          EXAMPLE333
https://example333.com        /archives                       EXAMPLE333
```

Index is set to **url**. But I can also treat it as a column with numerical index.

*How do I select only index (url) which contains **both** `.xml` and `archive` string in column `links`?*

Ie.

```
https://example333.com        /atom.xml                       EXAMPLE333
https://example333.com        /archives                       EXAMPLE333
```

But not

```
https://example222.com        /about/                         EXAMPLE222
https://example222.com        /about/                         EXAMPLE222
```

Obviously simple `.str.contains('archive|xml')` selects rows even when only one condition is met.

In this example, it would select also:

```
https://example.com           /feed.xml                       EXAMPLE
https://example.com           /tags.html                      EXAMPLE
```

Which is not what I want.

Solutions with or without `set_index` are both good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a groupby then apply a custom aggregate function:

```
def summarize(group):
    has_xml = group['links'].str.contains(r'\.xml')
    has_archive = group['links'].str.contains('archive')

    return group[has_xml | has_archive] if has_xml.any() and has_archive.any() else None

df.groupby('url').apply(summarize).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

Result:

```
                       url      links       title
8   https://example333.com  /atom.xml  EXAMPLE333
9   https://example333.com  /archives  EXAMPLE333
11  https://example333.com  /archives  EXAMPLE333
```

Answer (score 1):

First idea is use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for `Series` and converting to `set`s compare by both values if exist per groups:

```
s = df['links'].str.extract('(archive|xml)', expand=False)
m = s.groupby(df['url']).apply(set) >= set(['xml','archive'])
```

Then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to mask in original data and chain with another condition

```
df = df[df['url'].map(m) & s.notna()]
#alternative
#df = df[df['url'].map(m) & df['links'].str.contains('archive|xml')]
print (df)
                       url      links       title
8   https://example333.com  /atom.xml  EXAMPLE333
9   https://example333.com  /archives  EXAMPLE333
11  https://example333.com  /archives  EXAMPLE333
```

If want unique values per `url` add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df[df['url'].map(m) & s.notna()].drop_duplicates(['url','links'])
print (df)
                      url      links       title
8  https://example333.com  /atom.xml  EXAMPLE333
9  https://example333.com  /archives  EXAMPLE333
```

Another approach should be count matched values in 2 helper columns and test if both columns matchinf with compare summed values with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
a = df['links'].str.contains('archive')
b = df['links'].str.contains('xml')

mask = df.assign(a=a,b=b).groupby('url')['a','b'].transform('sum').gt(0).all(axis=1)

df = df[mask & (a | b)]
print (df)
8   https://example333.com  /atom.xml  EXAMPLE333
9   https://example333.com  /archives  EXAMPLE333
11  https://example333.com  /archives  EXAMPLE333
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want get only URLS that matches the conditions, here is code:

```
urls = df.groupby(level = 0).agg({'links': (lambda x: sum([(f in list(x.str.extract('(archive|xml)', expand=False))) for f in ['archive','xml']])==2)})['links']

print(urls)

Out[1]:
    https://example.com       False
    https://example222.com    False
    https://example333.com     True
    Name: links, dtype: bool

print(list(urls[urls].index))

Out[2]:
    ['https://example333.com']
```